# If logo id exists, hide another id on page in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to hide a `div` if a logo exists. Tried a few things with no joy, can you spot the error?

```
if ($('#mylogo').css('display', 'block') {
   $('#sign_up_now').css('display', 'none');
}
```

**and**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('#my_logo').length) {
       $('#sign_up_now').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

So if my my_logo is active **(display:block)** of even present. Hide the div with an **ID** of **sign_up_now**

Would be great to have two options working, as I might need to hide a div later if sign_up_now div exists too.

**EDIT**

When placing in the footer of the page, if running two JQuery functions. I assume they don't seperate script tags just closing off with a ;

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('#intrica_logo').css('display') == 'block') {
            $('#sign_up_now').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('tr#logout_button').css('display') == 'table-row') {
            $('tr#sign_up_now').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
</script>
```

or should it be

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('#my_logo').css('display') == 'block') {
            $('#sign_up_now').css('display', 'none');
        }
        if ($('tr#logout_button').css('display') == 'table-row') {
            $('tr#sign_up_now').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: is happening now?with present code?

Comment: Try `if ($('#mylogo').css('display') == 'block) {
        $('#sign_up_now').css('display', 'none');
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($('#mylogo').css('display') == 'block') {
    $('#sign_up_now').css('display', 'none');
}
});

or 

$(document).ready(function(){
if ($('#mylogo').css('display') == 'block') {
    $('#sign_up_now').hide();
}
});
```

put any of these examples.

Comment: Adding explanation will make this a better answer and help user understand the issue.

Comment: 1st one works a treat-thanks, if I wanted to hide a table row too ```<tr id="logout_button">``` . How would I use the length version?

Comment: Ticked, Please see edit - How should two functions be placed in footer please?

Answer (score 2):

try using :visible and `is()` to test if the logo is visible, use `hide()` to hide the logo

```
if ($('#mylogo').length && $('#mylogo').is(':visible')) {
    $('#sign_up_now').hide();
}
```

Comment: Elements with visibility hidden or opacity zero are considered to be visible, because they have space in the layout.

Comment: @AfnanAhmad thnx for the info but what has this got to do with my answer?

Comment: If you want to check if the element is visible display != none and ignoring the parents visibility then you will find that doing .`css("display") == 'none'` is not only faster, but will also give the `visibility` check accurately.

Comment: if the state of inactive menu is done using display:none/height/width=0 then this is accurate enough,why will anyone want to hide a menu with visibility/opacity?

Answer (score 1):

In your `if` statement you are assign the `display` property instead of checking.

Modify your code as below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('#mylogo').css('display') == 'block') {
    $('#sign_up_now').css('display', 'none');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get an element `display` property with the following snippet:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        if( $('#my_logo').css('display') == 'block' ) {
           $('#sign_up_now').css('display', 'none');
        } else {
        //element's display is not block       
        }
    });
```

Elements with visibility hidden or opacity zero are considered to be visible, because they have space in the layout. You can check if element is visible like the following snippet:

```
function isHidden (element) {
    return $(element).is(":hidden") || $(element).css("visibility") == "hidden" || $(element).css('opacity') == 0;
}


var isShowed = !isHidden(checkElement);
```

If you want to check element is visible `display != none` and ignoring the parents visibility then you will find that doing `.css("display") == 'none'` is faster and will give you accurate visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if( $('#my_logo').css('display') == 'block' ) {
        $('#sign_up_now').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $('#sign_up_now').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to your element and detect if element has `class` or no

```
if($("#mylogo").hasClass("visible")){
    $('#sign_up_now').css('display', 'none')
    $("#mylogo").removeClass("visible");
}
```